# regex for cutting a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am looking for a regexp in php which cut a string at the first `(<br>|<br />|<p>)`

I got something like this, but it is still not working

```
$newstring = preg_replace( '#< /?\s*(br|p) >.*$#i', '', $string );
```

For example, if `$string` is:

```
<b>this is a test</b><bR>and it is going on<br /> and so on<p>
```

expecting `$newstring` to be

```
<b>This is s test</b>
```

Comment: Providing a sample input and desired output is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you getting fancy with the regex? Why not just

```
$newstring = preg_replace('~(<br ?/?>|<p>).*~i', '', $string );
```

See [live demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/287cdbe9fc350291c0b7fac78d418d4c2511af70) of:

```
$string = '<b>this is a test</b><bR>and it is going on<br /> and so on<p>';
$newstring = preg_replace('~(<br ?/?>|<p>).*~i', '', $string );
echo $newstring;
```

Output:

```
<b>this is a test</b>
```